# пример необходимости использовать ссылку на указатель

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки, объявление

здравствуйте, хотел найти пример обязательного использования ссылки на указатель... так и не нашел...
вот, допустим, есть код:

```
template<typename T>
void ptr_diff(T*& ptr, size_t length) {
    delete[] ptr;
    ptr = new T[length];
    for(unsigned i=0u; i<length; ++i) {
        ptr[i] = i;
    }
}

int main() {
int* ptr = new int[5];
    for(unsigned i=0u; i<5; ++i) {
        ptr[i] = i*i;
    }
    for(unsigned i=0u; i<5; ++i) {
        std::cout<<ptr[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    ptr_diff(ptr, 5);
    for(unsigned i=0u; i<5; ++i) {
        std::cout<<ptr[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

к сожалению, все отработало правильно, значения по указателю изменились... хоть если бы было ptr_diff(T*& ptr, size_t length), хоть без ссылки на указатель... 
напишите пожалуйста какую-нибудь реализацию функции ptr_diff такую, чтобы обязательно понадобилась сигнатура функции ptr_diff(T*& ptr, size_t length) со ссылкой на указатель, а иначе чтобы значение по указателю не менялось или еще что-нибудь с ним случилось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас все отработало правильно именно потому, что вы передаете в функцию указатель по ссылке

```
template<typename T>
void ptr_diff(T*& ptr, size_t length) {
              ^^^^
//...
```

Если вы уберете ссылку из объявления функции

```
template<typename T>
void ptr_diff(T* ptr, size_t length) {
              ^^^^
//...
```

то увидите, что все будет работать, а точнее не работать, по-другому.:)

Так как вы в функции удаляете память, которую изначально выделили в `main` для указателя  `ptr` , а новое значение этот указатель не получает, так как функция имеет дело с копией указателя, а не с самим указателем.

Поэтому далее после вызова функции данный цикл имеет неопределенное поведение

```
ptr_diff(ptr, 5);
for(unsigned i=0u; i<5; ++i) {
    std::cout<<ptr[i]<<" ";
}
```

и скорей всего завершится аварийно, так как имеет место попытка обратиться к памяти, которая уже была освобождена вызовом функции.

Comment: ну вот, как ни странно, то если убрать ссылку, то все нормально остается) gcc 5.4

Comment: @xperious Ничего нормального нет. Имеет место неопределенное поведение программы. А это означает, что результат непредсказуем. Если вы запустите программу, скомпилированную с помощь. другого компилятора, то ничего "нормального" не будет.:)

Comment: жаль, что гцц даже ворнинг не выдает

Comment: @xperious Он и не может это сделать, так как в противном случае ему надо анализировать все функции, что они делают с указателями.

Comment: вот только одно не понятно: почему delete[] ptr распространяется на сам указатель, а new T[length] только на копию?

Comment: @xperious delete [] ptr; использует то значение, которое хранится в исходном указателе. А new присваивает возвращаемый новый адрес локальной переменной функции, а не переменной, обозначающей исходный указатель.

Comment: а почему delete[] ptr использует то именно то значение, которое хранится в исходном указателе?) логично предположить, что обнулиться память должна была по копии,  и присвоиться копии, а старое значение как было так и не изменялось

Comment: @xperious Потому что вы копию этого значение передали параметру функции, и при использовании delete[] это значение и используется как адрес удаляемой памяти. Обратного присвоения адреса новой выделенной памяти исходному указателю не происходит. Такое присвоение имеет место для локальной переменной - параметра функции, которая прекратит свое существование после выхода из функции.

Comment: спасибо, вот до этого не допер

Comment: @xperious Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)